# Copying bootstrap form elements from one theme to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building my first Yii2 app in bootstrap and I was looking at a few templates to base the UI in. The problem is that each one offers a few unique form elements that I like. Is it relatively easy to copy form elements from one theme to another?

For example, copying the Ui Elements > Tree View from http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0B30DGR into another template like http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0F0419C.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your experience in CSS and Javascript. I also customized on several occasions templates bootstrap changing some elements. First, it is whether you intend to do only the changes to the graphics and then only the changes to boostrap.css or if you want to supplement / modify the parts managed via javascrit. For graphics all template-type bootstrap behave the same way, then it needs to identify exactly which categories you care about and modify them with the catatteristiche want. For the part controlled by javascrit the situation is similar only the most delicate and complex.

Comment: Ok. I'm used to using things like Firebug and so forth to backtrace js and CSS calls. I assume that maybe it's a process of finding out which functions are called and copying them over, along with any supporting images that display the control. But I know that js can be rather complex for someone who isn't used to the structure. JQuery is pretty easy to understand.

Comment: Javascript is not more complex than other languages, it is to approach various problems with a certain order. Much depends on your experience in web programming, if you are very active expert is a totally viable even in a short time, but if you're not very experienced you should start with a few good elements and analyze your needs before you start.

Comment: I also use Yii2 and the process of creating a new version by the modified version of the file in the directory `vendor\bower\bootstrap\dist\.....`  and to make it available to the assets created at runtime by simply deleting in  `app\basic\web\assets\.. `the directory that contains the files you care about. I hope this could be useful for you and you could rate my answer